# What protocol does Akka.NET use to communicate to nodes in the cluster?

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster

For example, setting the `remote{}` configuration, does that also set the transport that is used internally for cluster communication, for example, the heartbeat messages.

I am not asking for any use case purpose I am asking so I better understand what's happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (Akka.NET 1.3) uses its own protocol for remote communication on top of TCP connection - only a single connection is used by every node-to-node connection. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6c1gVLyYcMM) discusses it in greater detail.

In future, it will probably change to match JVM version of akka - two major ideas are:

- "lanes": multiple connections for each pair of nodes, to avoid head-of-line blocking, that is inherent problem of TCP.
- Add support for other protocols, such as [Aeron](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/wiki/Protocol-Specification), which is also supported by akka on JVM.